# Customizing Ubuntu colors

Tags: 12.10, customization, libraries, cursor

What application is recommended to accomplish these:

1. How can I change my selection highlight color?
2. How can I change my cursors?
3. How can I include more libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the "cursor theme" in Ubuntu, install Ubuntu Tweak:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
ubuntu-tweak
```

Then, select "Tweaks" and then "Themes". In there you can change your "cursor theme" among other theme tweaks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change cursor and colours in a terminal:

Open a terminal window, click Edit, then Profile Preferences then edit the Cursor shape setting.

To 'include more libraries', click the Ubuntu icon in the top left of the screen - this opens the dash. Then type `Software` - the first thing that pops up is the Ubuntu Software Center - you use this to search for and install new programs (games, office suites, IDEs for programming, etc.)